# ssh - echo $SSH_CLIENT returns empty when executed on initial connect

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

when the command is attached to the ssh connection..

```
ssh -p $port -t root@$ip "echo $SSH_CLIENT; bash"
```

once it connects... there seems to be an echoing of a empty line.
in other words just a new line is being echo-ed on the server.

but if i manually paste

```
 echo $SSH_CLIENT
```

it works just fine.

why is this ? what can be the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is being expanded in the local shell, before the `ssh` command runs. As it is unset on the local shell, you are not getting anything, just a newline that `echo` produces by default, while being executed on remote shell.

You need to escape the `$` in front of `SSH_CLIENT` in any of the usual manners:

```
ssh ... 'echo $SSH_CLIENT; bash'
ssh ... "echo \$SSH_CLIENT; bash"
```

Note that, although it is not strictly necessary in this case, you should quote your variable expansions to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.

Answer (score 1):

`$SSH_CLIENT` is expanded first on the local host before ever running `ssh`; if it is not set, the remote host sees the command `echo; bash`. Use single quotes so that the *remote* shell sees the parameter:

```
ssh -p $port -t root@$ip 'echo $SSH_CLIENT; bash'
```