# SSH : connect .. execute .. printenv SSH_CONNECTION .. show only IP

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, tr

Here is the code:

```
command="ssh -p 2222 -t root@$ip";
command2='"printenv SSH_CONNECTION;bash"'
xfce4-terminal -x sh -c "$command $command2; bash"
```

output is:

```
 00.00.00.00 53011 10.245.0.225 2222
```

the first item was my ip. i repaced all numbers with 0's. 
the second item.. probably a PID or something.
the third item.. probably what cloud hosts call "private ip" thing.
the fourth item.. the ssh port.

What i want is to only print out my ip. 
and not all the other stuff.

in other words just the

```
  00.00.00.00
```

the cleanest.. the lightest.. the least resource consumption method..

Comment: Just to verify that all the extra invocations of `bash` are necessary: you want to open a new terminal that connects to the remote host, displays the IP address there, then leaves you in a remote shell, and when you exit *that* shell, the terminal stays open in a local shell?

Comment: See also [previous question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854287/ssh-echo-ssh-client-returns-empty-when-executed-on-initial-connect) and [previous question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858678/ssh-connect-execute-echo-ssh-connection-awk-print-1).

Comment: The values you see in `SSH_CONNECTION` is in the format `sourceIP sourcePort destinationIP destinationPort`. All you need to do is replace `printenv SSH_CONNECTION` with `echo \${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}`.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter substitution can be used to limit what `SSH_CONNECTION` expands to. (There's no need for `printenv`, because `SSH_CONNECTION` is a valid shell identifier.)

```
command="ssh -p 2222 -t root@$ip";
command2='"echo \${SSH_CONNECTION%% *};bash"'
xfce4-terminal -x sh -c "$command $command2; bash"
```

Comment: You have to escape: `\${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}`.

Comment: I don't think so. It won't be expanded, because the value assigned to `command2` is in single-quotes. It also won't be expanded when `$command2` is expanded, so the remote shell should see `echo ${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}; bash` as the command. (But this is why I don't try to pass ad-hoc scripts as arguments to `ssh`, let alone when the call to `ssh` itself is part of an argument.)

Comment: Oh, wait, you're right, because it *will* be expanded by `sh` before it runs `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using awk for example:

echo "00.00.00.00 53011 10.245.0.225 2222" | awk '{print $1}'

Comment: awk has escaping issues in  `command2='"printenv SSH_CONNECTION;bash"' ` lots of quotes are needed i believe.